# Make VS Code resolve require paths relative to project root

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

In my node application, I like to avoid relative `require` paths that look like:

```
const { compileTemplate } = require('../../util/compileTemplate')
```

Instead, I run my project from its root directory, setting  `NODE_PATH=$PWD`.  This lets me use `require` paths that are relative to the project root:

```
    const { compileTemplate } = require('util/compileTemplate')
```

This works well, and the application runs fine. VS Code, however, doesn't seem to be able to resolve these paths:

[image: VS Code not finding path]

I am guessing that I need to tell VS Code in some configuration setting to add the project root to `NODE_PATH`, or otherwise inform it that it should also use the project root when trying to resolve `require`s.

However, I haven't been able to figure out how.

How can I make VS Code recognize these `require`s?